# Programmatically resize framelayout

Tags: android, height, android-framelayout

I have something like that:

```
  <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/photo1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
     <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/photo2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </FrameLayout>
    <Fragment>

</Fragment>
    </FrameLayout>
```

And I want to resize that photo2 FrameLayout.

```
public void setScreenSize() {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.photo2);
    int screen_height = display.getHeight();
    screen_height = (int) (0.60*screen_height);
    LayoutParams parms = (LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
    parms.height = screen_height;
    }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: did you find any answer

Answer (score 2):

Are you setting the height back to the layout?

```
public void setScreenSize() {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.photo2);
    int screen_height = display.getHeight();
    screen_height = (int) (0.60*screen_height);
    LayoutParams parms = (LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
    parms.height = screen_height;
    // Set it back.
    layout.setLayoutParams(parms);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the size of FrameLyaout programmatically then copy and paste this code, its working 100%.

```
FrameLayout frame1 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.framelayout1);
frame1.getLayoutParams().height =460;
frame1.getLayoutParams().width = 350;
frame1.requestLayout();
```

Comment: I have tried above code but is not working in my case

Comment: actualImageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(Datas.received_uri.getPath()).getAbsolutePath(), options);
                ImageViewHeight = options.outHeight;
                ImageViewWidth = options.outWidth;

                img_baseview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);

                canvasView.getLayoutParams().height = ImageViewHeight;
                canvasView.getLayoutParams().width = ImageViewWidth;
                canvasView.requestLayout();